# How to make a call button in Sencha Touch

Tags: html, sencha-touch

how do I make a simple Call Button in Sencha Touch

My button is declared as:

```
var callButton = {
            xtype: "button",
            text: 'Call College',
            ui: 'custom-btn-confirm',         
            maxWidth: '360px',
            padding:    '0 80 0 80',
            centered: true,
            flex: 1,
            scope: this,
            style: 'color: #ffffff',


            handler: function() {
                console.log("Make a Phone Call");
                //document.location.href = "tel:00112233"; // This does not work


            }
```

Related

[Fire 'tel' link from button in Sencha Touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528290/fire-tel-link-from-button-in-sencha-touch)

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?127497-Firing-a-tel-link-from-a-button/page2&highlight=location.href

[How can make a device phone call by android using phoneGap and Sencha Touch 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999841/how-can-make-a-device-phone-call-by-android-using-phonegap-and-sencha-touch-2)

http://rickluna.com/wp/2012/02/making-a-phone-call-from-within-phonegap-in-android-and-ios/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace  button by

```
{html : "<a href='tel:{phone}' class='x-button call-button' target='_blank'>Call College</a>"}
```

Comment: I voted this approach, but please keep in mind it works only on android and not any longer on IOS 5. Instead I reccomedusing a Phonegap Plugin. Thanks